# Ruby sort the multidimensional array via their key

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I want to sort an array to sort in ascending or descending order.
My array contains hash keys and the values I want to sort are float, integer and string (names). Names can be alphabetic or alphanumeric. I want to create a method that would handle all the sortings. It will take array, column name and sort order and return the rest of the array sorted.
***The following is the JSON output. My array contains the hash keys.***

```
[
  {
    "sid": "101",
    "snumber": "798798",
    "name": "Anita 1",
    "time": 1800,
    "count": 32,
    "hour": "",
    "avg": 1
  },
  {
    "sid": "160",
    "snumber": "6546546",
    "name": "Anita 22",
    "time": 1300,
    "count": 30,
    "hour": "1",
    "avg": 1
  },
  {
    "sid": "120",
    "snumber": "6546546",
    "name": "Anita",
    "time": 2300,
    "count": 10,
    "hour": "2",
    "avg": 2
  }
]
```

I tried many things but couldn't get anything right. Here's my method:

```
def self.sort_by_alphabets(arr, sortColumnName, sortOrder) # sortOrder a: ASC,d: DESC
    column = sortColumnName.to_sym
    return arr.sort_by { |h| 
        if sortColumnName == 'sid' || sortColumnName = 'snumber' || sortColumnName =='hour'
            a = h[column].to_i
        else
            if h[column].is_a? String
                a = h[column].to_s
                type ='s'
            elsif h[column].is_a? Float
                a = h[column].to_f
                type ='f'
            else
                a = h[column].to_i
                type ='i'
            end

       if sortOrder == 'a'
        a.downcase
       else
        a.upcase
       end

    }
  end
```

Can anyone help me out?

An expected output is a sorted array. Say if I want to sort an array using `sid` in ascending order then result array will sort by sid in the mentioned order, likewise for other keys. However, array can only be sorted in any one key at a time.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Why do you check to see if a value is a string then convert it to a string? What does upcase/downcase have to do with ascending/descending sorts? Why do you throw away `type` after setting it? So many questions.

Comment: @DaveNewton I used type here to map it later for choosing the sort method to float, integer or string if there are different methods for them. I was surfing the internet and I found different methods for different variable type.

Comment: Do you want to sort the array itself depending on the values of some specific key which is contained in every hash? Or do you want to sort the hash objects so that their keys are in alphabetical order? In the first case (as some of the answers already mention) `sort(&block)` and `sort_by(&block)` will be your friends. You can simply do `array.sort {|h| h['snumber'] }` to sort it by snumber and this can easily be packed into a method which gets the key as an argument. If the latter is the case you can just do `array.map{|h| h.sort_by{|k, v| k}.to_h }`.

Answer (score 3):

**Code**

```
def sort_by_value(arr, key, ascending = true)
  arr.sort_by do |h|
    v = h[key]
    raise TypeError, "#{v}.class => #{v.class} invalid" unless
      (v.kind_of?(Numeric) && !v.is_a?(Complex)) || v.is_a?(String)
    Float(v) rescue v.downcase
  end.tap { |a| a.reverse! if ascending == false }
end
```

See [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by), [Object#kind_of?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-kind_of-3F) and [Kernel#Float](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Float).

I have assumed that when a value is a string that represents a numeric value (other than a complex number), the sort is to be done on the associated number. `Float(v)` attempts to convert the string `v` to a float. If successful it returns float; else it raises an exception that is rescued (in line), causing `v.downcase` to be returned.

**Examples**

```
arr = [
  { "name"=>"Anita 1",  "time"=>18, "wt"=>2.31,  "inbr"=>  "79", "fnbr"=>"-2.31"    },
  { "name"=>"Anita 22", "time"=>13, "wt"=>-12.4, "inbr"=> "654", "fnbr"=>"12.4"     },
  { "name"=>"bubba",    "time"=>23, "wt"=>12.84, "inbr"=>"-654", "fnbr"=>"-1284e-2" }
]

sort_by_value(arr, "name")
  #=> [{"name"=>"Anita 1", "time"=>18, "wt"=>2.31, "inbr"=>"79","fnbr"=>"-2.31"}
  #    {"name"=>"Anita 22", "time"=>13, "wt"=>-12.4, "inbr"=>"654","fnbr"=>"12.4"},
  #    {"name"=>"bubba", "time"=>23, "wt"=>12.84, "inbr"=>"-654","fnbr"=>"-1284e-2"}]
sort_by_value(arr, "name", false)
  #=> [{"name"=>"bubba", "time"=>23, "wt"=>12.84, "inbr"=>"-654",  "fnbr"=>"-1284e-2"},
  #    {"name"=>"Anita 22", "time"=>13, "wt"=>-12.4, "inbr"=>"654",  "fnbr"=>"12.4"},
  #    {"name"=>"Anita 1", "time"=>18, "wt"=>2.31, "inbr"=>"79",  "fnbr"=>"-2.31"}]

sort_by_value(arr, "time")
  #=> [{"name"=>"Anita 22", "time"=>13, "wt"=>-12.4, "inbr"=>"654", "fnbr"=>"12.4"},
  #    {"name"=>"Anita 1", "time"=>18, "wt"=>2.31, "inbr"=>"79", "fnbr"=>"-2.31"},
  #    {"name"=>"bubba", "time"=>23, "wt"=>12.84, "inbr"=>"-654", "fnbr"=>"-1284e-2"}]
sort_by_value(arr, "time", false)
  #=> [{"name"=>"bubba", "time"=>23, "wt"=>12.84, "inbr"=>"-654", "fnbr"=>"-1284e-2"},
  #    {"name"=>"Anita 1", "time"=>18, "wt"=>2.31, "inbr"=>"79", "fnbr"=>"-2.31"},
  #    {"name"=>"Anita 22", "time"=>13, "wt"=>-12.4, "inbr"=>"654", "fnbr"=>"12.4"}]
```

```
sort_by_value(arr, "wt")
  #=> [{"name"=>"Anita 22", "time"=>13, "wt"=>-12.4, "inbr"=>"654", "fnbr"=>"12.4"},
  #    {"name"=>"Anita 1", "time"=>18, "wt"=>2.31, "inbr"=>"79", "fnbr"=>"-2.31"},
  #    {"name"=>"bubba", "time"=>23, "wt"=>12.84, "inbr"=>"-654", "fnbr"=>"-1284e-2"}]
sort_by_value(arr, "wt", false)
  #=> [{"name"=>"bubba", "time"=>23, "wt"=>12.84, "inbr"=>"-654", "fnbr"=>"-1284e-2"},
  #    {"name"=>"Anita 1", "time"=>18, "wt"=>2.31, "inbr"=>"79", "fnbr"=>"-2.31"},
  #    {"name"=>"Anita 22", "time"=>13, "wt"=>-12.4, "inbr"=>"654", "fnbr"=>"12.4"}]

sort_by_value(arr, "inbr")
  #=> [{"name"=>"bubba", "time"=>23, "wt"=>12.84, "inbr"=>"-654", "fnbr"=>"-1284e-2"},
  #    {"name"=>"Anita 1", "time"=>18, "wt"=>2.31, "inbr"=>"79", "fnbr"=>"-2.31"},
  #    {"name"=>"Anita 22", "time"=>13, "wt"=>-12.4, "inbr"=>"654", "fnbr"=>"12.4"}]
sort_by_value(arr, "inbr", false)
  #=> [{"name"=>"Anita 22", "time"=>13, "wt"=>-12.4, "inbr"=>"654", "fnbr"=>"12.4"},
  # {"name"=>"Anita 1", "time"=>18, "wt"=>2.31, "inbr"=>"79", "fnbr"=>"-2.31"},
  # {"name"=>"bubba", "time"=>23, "wt"=>12.84, "inbr"=>"-654", "fnbr"=>"-1284e-2"}]

sort_by_value(arr, "fnbr")
  #=> [{"name"=>"bubba", "time"=>23, "wt"=>12.84, "inbr"=>"-654", "fnbr"=>"-1284e-2"},
  #    {"name"=>"Anita 1", "time"=>18, "wt"=>2.31, "inbr"=>"79", "fnbr"=>"-2.31"},
  #    {"name"=>"Anita 22", "time"=>13, "wt"=>-12.4, "inbr"=>"654", "fnbr"=>"12.4"}]
sort_by_value(arr, "fnbr", false)
  #=> [{"name"=>"Anita 22", "time"=>13, "wt"=>-12.4, "inbr"=>"654", "fnbr"=>"12.4"},
  #    {"name"=>"Anita 1", "time"=>18, "wt"=>2.31, "inbr"=>"79", "fnbr"=>"-2.31"},
  #    {"name"=>"bubba", "time"=>23, "wt"=>12.84, "inbr"=>"-654", "fnbr"=>"-1284e-2"}]
```

Comment: Why `Integer()`? It seems more concise to go with `Float(v) rescue v.downcase` Which would handle all the cases other than the raised `StandardError` (which, if you don't mind my quibbling, seems more appropriate as a `TypeError`)

Comment: Excellent suggestions, @engineersmnky! Very clever  but reads well also. I've made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

#### Input

```
ary = [{
        "sid" => "101",
        "snumber" => "798798",
        "name" => "Ben",
        "time" => 1800,
        "count" => 32,
        "hour" => "",
        "avg" => 1
      },
      {
        "sid" => "160",
        "snumber" => "6546546",
        "name" => "anita",
        "time" => 1300,
        "count" => 30,
        "hour" => "1",
        "avg" => 1
      },
      {
        "sid" => "120",
        "snumber" => "6546546",
        "name" => "Jake",
        "time" => 2300,
        "count" => 10,
        "hour" => "2",
        "avg" => 2
      }]
```

#### Solution

I assume you want to sort by any column whether its value be a number or a string. I don't know why you used `downcase` in your attempt. If that has a special meaning, please mention. I will update the answer.

```
def sort_by_key(ary, column, order)
  # I am working on hashes with stringified keys, so not doing `to_sym` on `column`. You can uncomment below line if your hashes has symbol keys.
  # column = column.to_sym

  order = order.to_sym
  raise 'Unknown sort order' unless %i[asc desc].include?(order)

  ary.sort do |x, y|
    order == :asc ?
      x[column] <=> y[column] :
      y[column] <=> x[column]
  end 
end

sort_by_key(ary, 'sid', :desc)
 => [{"sid"=>"160", "snumber"=>"6546546", "name"=>"anita", "time"=>1300, "count"=>30, "hour"=>"1", "avg"=>1},
     {"sid"=>"120", "snumber"=>"6546546", "name"=>"Jake", "time"=>2300, "count"=>10, "hour"=>"2", "avg"=>2},
     {"sid"=>"101", "snumber"=>"798798", "name"=>"Ben", "time"=>1800, "count"=>32, "hour"=>"", "avg"=>1}]

sort_by_key(ary, 'name', :asc)
 => [{"sid"=>"101", "snumber"=>"798798", "name"=>"Ben", "time"=>1800, "count"=>32, "hour"=>"", "avg"=>1},
     {"sid"=>"120", "snumber"=>"6546546", "name"=>"Jake", "time"=>2300, "count"=>10, "hour"=>"2", "avg"=>2},
     {"sid"=>"160", "snumber"=>"6546546", "name"=>"anita", "time"=>1300, "count"=>30, "hour"=>"1", "avg"=>1}]
```

See how "anita" comes last as all uppercase letter come before downcase letters by default in sorting.

If you want to sort the names irrespective of the case, modify the method as below:

```
def sort_by_key(ary, column, order)
  ...
  ary.sort do |x, y|
    val_x, val_y = [x, y].map { |hash| hash[column] }
    val_x, val_y = [val_x, val_y].map(&:downcase) if [val_x, val_y].all? { |v| v.respond_to?(:downcase) }
    order == :asc ?
      val_x <=> val_y :
      val_y <=> val_x
  end
end

sort_by_key(ary, 'name', :asc)
 => [{"sid"=>"160", "snumber"=>"6546546", "name"=>"anita", "time"=>1300, "count"=>30, "hour"=>"1", "avg"=>1},
     {"sid"=>"101", "snumber"=>"798798", "name"=>"Ben", "time"=>1800, "count"=>32, "hour"=>"", "avg"=>1},
     {"sid"=>"120", "snumber"=>"6546546", "name"=>"Jake", "time"=>2300, "count"=>10, "hour"=>"2", "avg"=>2}]
```

**Note:** You have the value of key `"hour"` stored as strings. So, sorting will work on them like any other string e.g. `"hour"` value "12" will come **before** value "2". To fix this, you can convert string values for `"hour"` to integers using [`String#to_i`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_i) on them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will, definitely give it a shot. I used `downcase` because I saw it somewhere to sort alphabets.

Comment: By default sorting between uppercase and lowercase letters work as: `['A', 'a', 'B', 'c'].sort` => `["A", "B", "a", "c"]`

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper i have updated the answer with an example to show how sorting on strings with different cases will work.

Comment: I tried, its not working at all. I am using is wrong? `array = sort_by_key(array, name.to_sym, asc.to_sym)` In the next line i am printing the response `array.to_json` . Nothing seems to be working. I tried to print `val_x, val_y`, they are both empty. However, `hash[column]` is printing the names if i choose the column `'name'`

Comment: please note `"hour" => "12"` would be sorted before `"hour" => "2"` because of how `String#<=>` works

Comment: @engineersmnky I agree with you. Ideally, "hour" value should be stored as `Integer` for proper sorting like the value for "count". You can't tell if you need to convert a string to integer before sorting unless you hardcode it for some known keys.

Comment: Thanks for the note though. I will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to patch the array class you can do as follow, for example:

```
module ArrayPatch
  def sort_by_key(key, order = :asc)
    sorted = sort_by { |hash| hash[key] }
    sorted.reverse! if order == :desc
    sorted
  end
end

Array.include ArrayPatch
```

The default order is `:asc` and the order parameter can be skipped:

```
array.sort_by_key(:name)
# => [{:sid=>"120", :snumber=>"6546546", :name=>"Anita", :time=>2300, :count=>10, :hour=>"2", :avg=>2}, {:sid=>"101", :snumber=>"798798", :name=>"Anita 1", :time=>1800, :count=>32, :hour=>"", :avg=>1}, {:sid=>"160", :snumber=>"6546546", :name=>"Anita 22", :time=>1300, :count=>30, :hour=>"1", :avg=>1}]
```

Or add :desc to reverse the order:

```
array.sort_by_key(:name, :desc)
#=> [{:sid=>"160", :snumber=>"6546546", :name=>"Anita 22", :time=>1300, :count=>30, :hour=>"1", :avg=>1}, {:sid=>"101", :snumber=>"798798", :name=>"Anita 1", :time=>1800, :count=>32, :hour=>"", :avg=>1}, {:sid=>"120", :snumber=>"6546546", :name=>"Anita", :time=>2300, :count=>10, :hour=>"2", :avg=>2}]
```

I omitted any error handling on parameters.

**EDIT:** This may fail with string representing number: `"1", "12", "2"` is an ordered sequence of String class objects, but expectation is `"1", "2", "12"`. In case, the best option is https://stackoverflow.com/a/51215213/5239030

Comment: Just so you know, it will do 2 iterations on input array in case of `:desc` order.

Comment: please note `"hour" => "12"` would be sorted before `"hour" => "2"` because of how `String#<=>` works

Comment: Yes. I missed it! Thank you. Edited with a warning.