# Sorting by integers represented as strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, sorting

I would like sort array of ActiveRecord objects by related object's attribute value. Meaning something like this:
Item has one product which has an attribute SKU. The SKU is mostly integer stored as a string, but could be alphanumeric as well.

```
sorted = items.sort_by { |item| Integer(item.product.sku) } rescue items
```

For now in case of error the items with original order returns.
What would I like to do?
Extend the Array class to achieve something like:

```
items.numeric_sort { |item| item.product.sku }
```

What I did so far?
1. Building a lambda expression and passing it

```
class Array
  def numeric_sort(&lambda)
    if lambda.respond_to? :call
      self.sort_by(&lambda) rescue self
    else
      self.sort_by { |el| Integer(el) } rescue self
    end
  end
end

product_bin = lambda { |task_item| Integer(item.product.bin) }  
items.numeric_sort(&product_bin)
```

2. Building lambda expression from methods chain

```
class Object
  def send_chain(keys)
    keys.inject(self, :send)
  end
end

class Array
  def numeric_sort_by(*args)
    (args.length == 1) ? lam = lambda {|el| Integer(el.send(args))} : lam = lambda {|el| Integer(el.send_chain(args))}
    self.sort_by(&lam) rescue self
  end
end

items.numeric_sort_by(:product, :sku)
```

Is it all makes any sense?
Can you please point me in the right direction to implement the syntax I mentioned above, if it is possible at all.
Thanks.

EDIT: the sku could be alphanumeric as well. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51215213/5239030

Comment: Close, but I would like a suggestion hot to implement the desired syntax. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `items` data to work on?

Comment: @iGian items = [ {id: 1, product: {sku: "6234324"}, {id: 2, product: {sku: "342343}}] .. in reality those are AR objects not hashes.

Comment: Why not `items.sort_by { |item| item.product.sku.to_i }`? Doesn't fail if sku is somehow not a valid integer string.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it would work like charm unless there is a sku like "ABC123".. sorry for not mentioning it in the question.

Comment: @Anton: "The SKU is integer stored as a string" - well, those are just strings then?  Can't sort them as integers if they aren't integers, no? Must be I'm not understanding something about the question.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I've updated the question. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev In case of an alphanumeric value in one or more of the sku's the original un ordered array of items should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

There is no error handling.
It's just an idea to develop if you like it.

```
class Array
  def numeric_sort_by(*args)
    self.sort_by do |element|
      object = element
      args.size.times { |n| object = object.send(args[n]) }
      object.to_f
    end
  end
end

items.numeric_sort_by 'product', 'sku'
```

Comment: Thanks, but you implemented the same idea as I did only without opening the Object. I would like to: items.numeric_sort { |item| item.product.sku } if possible.

Answer (score 0):

So the straightforward implementation was:

```
sorted = items.sort_by { |item| Integer(item.product.sku) } rescue items
```

And the desired was:

```
items.numeric_sort_by { |item| item.product.sku }
```

I was manage to achieve it by yielding a block into the sort_by:

```
class Array
  def numeric_sort_by(&block)
    return to_enum :numeric_sort_by unless block_given?
    self.sort_by { |element| Integer(yield(element)) } rescue self
  end
end
```